# Consulta no Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

Galera to usando firebase pela primeira vez, e to com um problema.
Quero fazer uma consulta no banco de dados 1x 
mas no meu console aparece que foi consultado várias vezes.

```
        var contador1 = firebase.database() .ref();

    contador1.set({
    Contador: {
      number:1
   }
});

var contando = firebase.database() .ref();

contando.orderByChild("number") .on("child_added", function(data) {
   console.log(data.val() .number);
});
```

to usando esse código!

No caso eu queria colocar lá variavel 1, depois ele iria consultar no banco ler a variavel e somar +1

Basicamente fazer um contador que trabalhe com o banco de dados!

Answer (score -1):

A pergunta não está muito clara, mas pelo que eu percebi, você está tentando fazer algo assim:

```
var contando = firebase.database() .ref().child("Contador/number");

contando.once("value", function(data) {
    var number = data.val();
    console.log(number);
    number++;
    contando.set(number);

});
```